# Correct termiology for documentation

Tags: documentation, terminology, delimiter, escaping

The documentation below is for a module, which has now been "decommissioned"
and I'm writing it's replacement.
Before i write the replacement I want to get my terms right.
I know the terms are wrong in the documentation - it was hacked together quickly
so i could instruct a college working on the hardware side of this project on how to use a program I'ld made.
Full documentary can be found [here](http://wiki.ucc.asn.au/LURC/FrontEnd) for any who are interested (in so much as has been written and added to our wiki), the Website may only be available to certain IPS's (depends on you ISP - university internet connections are most likely to work), and the SVN repo is private.

So there are alot of terms that are wrong.
such as. 
**deliminators**

**formatted string containing value expressions** (might now be wrong but is hard to say)

What are the correct terms for these.
And what other mistakes have I made

```
    ==== formatted string containing value expressions ====
    Before I start on actual programs an explanation of:
    "formatted string containing value expressions" and how to encode values in them.

    The ''formatted string containing value expressions'' is at the core of doing low level transmission.
    We know the decimal 65, hex 41, binary 0100 0001, and the ascii character 'A' all have the same binary representation, so to tell which we are using we have a series of deliminators - numbers preceded by: 
    # are decimal 
    $ are Hex 
    @ are binary 
    No deliminator, then ascii. 

    Putting a sign indicator after the deliminator is optional. It is required if you want to send a negative number.

    You may put muliple values in the same string.
    eg: "a#21@1001111$-0F"

    All values in a ''formatted string containing value expressions'' must be in the range -128 to 255 (inclusive) as they must fit in 8bytes (other values will cause an error). Negative numbers have the compliment of 2 representation for their binary form.

    There are some problems with ascii - characters that can't be sent (in future versions this will be fixed by giving ascii a delineator and some more code to make that deliminator work, I think). 
    Characters that can't be sent:
     * The delineator characters: $#@
     * Numbers written immediately after a value that could have contained those digits:
      * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 for decimal
      * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,A,B,C,D,E,F for hex
      * 0,1 for binary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, deliminator would probably be delimiter, although I notice your text has both delineator and deliminator in it - perhaps deliminator is a special delimiter/terminator combination :-)

However, a delimiter is usually used to separate fields and is usually present no matter what. What you have is an optional prefix which dictates the following field type. So I would probably call that a "prefix" or "type prefix" instead.

The "formatted string containing value expressions" I would just call a "value expression string" or "value string" to change it to a shorter form.

One other possible problem:

> must be in the range -128 to 255 (inclusive) as they must fit in 8bytes

I think you mean 8 *bits*.

Comment: value expression string is still too long, hmmm. maybe following the "Bad Namign guide" VlxprssnStrng would be better, jk.
Are you sure deliminator shouldnt'  be escape character?

Comment: i think that indeed is is another error in the documentation "8bit" I knew there were lots.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
     ==== Value string encoding  ====
    The value string is at the core of the data used for low level
    transmissions.

    Within the value string the following refixes are used:
    # decimal
    $ Hex
    @ binary
    No prefix - ASCII.

    An optional sign may be included after the delimiter for negative numbers.
    Negative numbers are represented using twos complement.

    The value string may contain multiple values:
    eg: "a#21@1001111$-0F"

    All elements of the value string must represent an 8bit value and must
    be in the range -128 to 255

    When using ASCII representation the following characters that can't be sent
     * The delineator characters: $#@ (use prefixed hex value.)
     * Numbers written immediately after a value that could have
       contained those digits:
      * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 for decimal
      * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,A,B,C,D,E,F for hex
      * 0,1 for binary
```